# Why is max width setting itself as the default width for the element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, socket.io

I was making a chat app, so I have used the CSS for the class to which incoming messages will be assigned but the problem here is that when I set the max-width I expect the width of the container element to be how much content it holds with a limit of up to 70% of the actual window but here the message width is becoming equal to the max-width

```
.chat-message-box {
max-width: 50%;
background: rgba(196, 68, 235, 0.5);
margin: 5px;
margin-top: 25px;
margin-right: 20px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 20px;
text-justify: auto;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The `max-width` is behaving in this way because it is suppose to behave like this. The `max-width` property come into effect when the width of the contents become greater than the provided width, in your case it is 50%, here this property is adjusting the content to the 50% width of the container.

Comment: but how can i make it work the way i want like i want the size to be fitting to content till the width of 50% is reached